# How to find the distance between 2 regions?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

RegionNearest gives a point in the region that is nearest another point, but what about the nearest point about another *region*? I'd like to find the minimum linear distance between any two points on the boundaries of two separate regions.

```
dm = RegionPlot@{DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[1, {25, 2}], 
   DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[{1, 2}, {25, 2}]}
```

[image]

My naive first approach is slow:

```
dist[r1_, r2_] := Min[EuclideanDistance[RegionNearest[r2, #], #] & /@ 
   RandomPoint[RegionBoundary[r1], 100]]
```

Comment: That's not really a very good distance measure because the dist from region1 to region2 is different from the distance between region2 and region1.

Comment: Are you restricting consideration to convex regions?

Comment: @mikado no most of my examples are concave

Answer (score 11):

`NMinimize` (or `NMinValue`) with a region constraint would work:

```
{r1, r2} = {DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[1, {25, 2}], 
   DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[{1, 2}, {25, 2}]};
sol = {NMinimize[RegionDistance[r1, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ r2], 
   NMinimize[RegionDistance[r2, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ r1]}
```

> `{{0.410122, {x -> 1.13287, y -> 1.26539}}, {0.410122, {x -> 0.859349, y -> 0.9598}}}`

Visualize the output:

```
Show[RegionPlot[{r1, r2}], 
 Graphics[{Line[#], {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@#}} &[
   {x, y} /. sol[[All, -1]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well,It's seem your answer first.

Answer (score 7):

```
dm = RegionPlot@{r1 = DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[1, {25, 2}], 
   r2 = DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[{1, 2}, {25, 2}]}
```

[image]

If you just want to find the min distance:

```
MinValue[EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}], 
 Element[{x2, y2}, r2], {Element[{x1, y1}, r1], 
  Element[{x2, y2}, r2]}]
```

> 0.292573

If you want to find the point in the meantime.

```
result = Minimize[EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}], 
  Element[{x2, y2}, r2], {Element[{x1, y1}, r1], 
   Element[{x2, y2}, r2]}]
```

> {0.292573,{x1->0.880152,y1->0.987411,x2->1.05027,y2->1.22544}}

Show the point:

```
Show[dm, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], 
   Point[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. Last[result]]}]]
```

[image]

ps:But I don't know why the `MinValue` and `Minimize` all return a machine precision number.

Comment: Hm, I think because the inputs are machine precision numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For these "nice" regions:

```
dm = RegionPlot@{r1 = DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[1, {25, 2}], 
   r2 = DelaunayMesh@RandomReal[{1, 2}, {25, 2}]}
rb1 = RegionBoundary[r1];
rb2 = RegionBoundary[r2];
rn1 = RegionNearest[r1][MeshPrimitives[rb2, 0] /. Point[x__] :> x];
rn2 = RegionNearest[r2][MeshPrimitives[rb1, 0] /. Point[x__] :> x];
rd1 = RegionDistance[r2, #] & /@ rn1;
rd2 = RegionDistance[r1, #] & /@ rn2;
min1 = Min[rd1];
min2 = Min[rd2];
pos1 = DeleteDuplicates[Extract[rn1, Position[rd1, min1]]][[1]];
pos2 = DeleteDuplicates[Extract[rn2, Position[rd2, min2]]][[1]];
Show[dm, ListPlot[rn1], ListPlot[rn2], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[pos1], Green, Point[pos2], 
   Black, Line[{pos1, pos2}], 
   Text[Framed[EuclideanDistance[pos1, pos2]], (pos1 + pos2)/
     2, {1, -0.5}]}]]
```

[image]